# Ensure existence of table with particular definition, Postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

In the category of "wouldn't it be nice if this SQL feature existed":

```
ENSURE TABLE name ( columns... );
```

behaves exactly like CREATE TABLE if the table doesn't already exist.   If the table *does* exist, it compares the columns, constraints, etc. to the existing schema and throws an error if they don't  match.  If they do match, it's a no-op.  Similarly, `ENSURE INDEX`, `ENSURE TYPE`, etc.

Given that this feature does not exist, what is the best way to accomplish the same effect?  Underlying database engine is PostgreSQL 9.1.  I'm currently using the Psycopg2 client library for Python.  Switching to some other client library and/or add-on library would be fine; changing implementation language ... is not preferred, but I suppose I could shell out to a self-contained "now validate the expected schema" script.  Upgrading to a newer Postgres is also not preferred but I'll do it if it makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using something like

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'table';
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'table';
```

Comment: Thanks, I can imagine a solution *starting* with this, but I'm looking for something complete in itself.

Comment: @Zack The complete code could be somewhat complex. If you don't show the use case and how relevant it is then I guess people will not be motivated enough to write it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [pgTap](http://pgtap.org/), a unit testing framework for PostgreSQL, for this kind of requirement. It works out of the box for PostgreSQL versions 9.1+.

I run this frequently against development versions of the database.  I don't have a need to run it against production databases, but I don't see anything wrong with that as long as you're careful.